# В чем разница между параметрами объявленного типа и выводимого типа в лямбда-выражениях?

Tags: java, лямбда-выражение

Параметры **выводимого типа** в лямбда-выражении

```
(x, y) -> x+y
```

Параметры **объявленного типа** в лямбда-выражении

```
(int x, int y) -> x+y
```

В чем разница между параметрами **объявленного типа** и **выводимого типа** в лямбда-выражениях?

Comment: Объявленный тип объявляется явно, выводимый - выводится из контекста. Вроде очевидно?

Comment: @Nofate может не соображаю уже, с выводимыми не могу определиться, они из какого контекста? из окружающего класса, где эта лямбда прописана?

Comment: А вы раскройте лямбду в полноценный анонимный класс и сразу станет понятнее

Comment: @TimurVI, конечно. Вы же подставляете лямбду в конкретное место, где требуются конкретные типы.